# Cant get tabulous gem to render controller action views on same page without tabs disappearing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am a ruby on rails newbie and developing a rails 3.1 app which includes tabulous gem with twitter-bootstrap and formtastic-bootstrap gems.

I have a control panel in my application under a namespaced area.

Under the namespaced area in the views directory, I have a control panel directory with view pages underneath it that don't correspond to any controller actions except 1 view page that relates to a controller called controlpanel_controller.rb action called control panel which serves as the main page of the control panel.

directory structures are as follows:

app/controllers/manager/controlpanel_controller.rb

app/views/manager/controlpanel/controlpanel.html.erb

app/views/manager/controlpanel/project.html.erb

app/views/manager/controlpanel/graphs.html.erb

I believe what I am trying to do is simple, I have created a nav menu which links to the different views under this control panel directory and what I want is to display tabs in one of the views(project.html.erb) when a user clicks a link in the nav menu labeled project.

The problem:
I have managed to implement the tabs I require which map to different controller actions and show in the view but upon clicking on a tab, the tabulous gem is not rendering the action views on the same page but instead linking me to another page. So basically the tabs disappear and I am routed to the controller view action of the tab I will have clicked on as opposed to being kept on the same page.  Can anyone offer any advise on why this isnt working as intended? because I cant see where I am going wrong.

I have included the code currently in my project.html.erb view file and tabulous.rb file below.

**project.html.erb:**

```
 <ul class="tabs" >
        <%= tabs %>
    </ul>
```

**tabulous.rb:**

```
     config.tabs do
    [
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
      #    TAB NAME                     |    DISPLAY TEXT       |    PATH                    |    VISIBLE?    |    ENABLED?    #
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
      [    :manager_controlpanel_tab    ,    'Control panel'    ,    ''                      ,    false       ,    true        ],
      [    :manager_tasks_tab           ,    'Tasks'            ,    :manager_tasks_path     ,    true        ,    true        ],
      [    :manager_graphs_tab          ,    'Graphs'           ,    :manager_graphs_path    ,    true        ,    true        ],
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
      #    TAB NAME                     |    DISPLAY TEXT       |    PATH                    |    VISIBLE?    |    ENABLED?    #
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    ]
  end

  #-------------
  #   ACTIONS
  #-------------
  #
  # This is where you hook up actions with tabs.  That way tabulous knows
  # which tab and subtab to mark active when an action is rendered.
  #
  # CONTROLLER
  #   the name of the controller
  # ACTION
  #   the name of the action, or :all_actions
  # TAB
  #   the name of the tab or subtab that is active when this action is rendered

  config.actions do
    [
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
      #    CONTROLLER               |    ACTION          |    TAB                          #
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
      [    :manager_controlpanel    ,    :all_actions    ,    :manager_controlpanel_tab    ],
      [    :manager_tasks           ,    :all_actions    ,    :manager_tasks_tab           ],
      [    :manager_graphs          ,    :all_actions    ,    :manager_graphs_tab          ],
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
      #    CONTROLLER               |    ACTION          |    TAB                          #
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    ]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've organized your controllers, actions and views differently than what tabulous expects.  For example, you say "what I want is to display tabs in one of the views", but for server-side tab solutions (like tabulous and TabsOnRails), each tab's content should be a different view.

What should happen is that if you have four tabs, you should have four actions--one for each tab.  And these four actions should have their own view.  You should call the tabs helper in a layout, not an individual view.

So either you need to re-organize your actions and views, or what you're trying to do doesn't fit with tabulous (perhaps you are wanting Ajax tabs?).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Each tab does have its own action and views and what Im attempting to do is call the tabs helper in a static page as opposed to the layout file. I will have a look into the ajax tabs option.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to move the code below into a layout. For exemple, to application.html.erb:

```
#app/application.html.erb
<ul class="tabs" > 
    <%= tabs %> 
 </ul>
```